# Refering Column with a index in Pandas Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using python 2.7.13 and pandas in Jupyter notebook. 
I have the following data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pko9oRmCllAxipZoa3aoztGZfPAD2iwj/view?usp=sharing
which is available on the following source
https://towardsdatascience.com/random-forest-in-python-24d0893d51c0
I am trying to call columns using numbers for example the names of the columns are 
Out[16]:
Index([u'year', u'month', u'day', u'week', u'temp_2', u'temp_1', u'average',
       u'actual', u'forecast_noaa', u'forecast_acc', u'forecast_under',
       u'friend'],
      dtype='object')

so instead of using df1=df[['year','average','actual','friend']]
can I use df1=df[[1,2,3,4]]

I am trying to use index instead of column numbers but I am getting error that index not found whereas in all over the tutorials on internet, it works pretty well. Can anyone help me in that please....

Comment: You need to use `df.iloc[[1,2,3,4],:]` in the case you want these indices

Comment: Yea, I know iloc and loc but in the tutorials on YouTube and internet, I dont know how do they directly select a column using just index. Like they just write df1=df[1,2,3] and columns are selected. That looked really strange. thats why I am asking that if it is possible to do it or not. But yea you are write using iloc and loc is the right option.